# Sniffing BLE with multiple NRF52840-DONGLEs?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, nordic

Nordic provides hardware, firmware and software to sniff BLE in conjuction with Wireshark:

- https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/nRF52840-Dongle
- https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=/ug_nrf52840_dongle/UG/nrf52840_Dongle/getting_started.html
- https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-sniffer-for-bluetooth-le
- https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/ug_sniffer_ble/UG/sniffer_ble/intro.html
- https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/ug_sniffer_ble/UG/sniffer_ble/capturing_multiple.html

It supports using multiple hardware interfaces.
I thought I'd read some time ago that this would be advantageous for sniffing BLE due to channel hopping or something similar, and I have the number three (interfaces) stuck in my head - but I can't seem to find any info on this, so:

- what are the advantages of multiple interfaces for sniffing BLE in this context?
- does the documentation recommend a number of interfaces, if so, where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BLE has 40 operating channels, 37 of them for data exchange, and 3 for advertising. When advertising, the BLE peripheral broadcasts a very short (few mSec) packet on each of the 3 channels in sequence. The BLE central device can only receive one channel at a time, so it scans the 3 frequencies in sequence. It has to spend a fair amount of time listening on each channel in order to pick up the short advertising pulse, and depending on the advertising and scanning timing parameters, it could take several seconds to pick up the peripheral's pulse.

If you set up 3 BLE devices, each programmed to continuously receive one of the 3 advertising channels, the system would pick up the advertising immediately, avoiding the typical lag when scanning. It's not a practical design for a battery-powered device, but if you really need to pick up every advertisement immediately, that would do it.

There's only a small advantage to using 3 devices. If you set up just one device, listening on just one of the advertising channels, it would pick up the advertisement within a few mSec of the more elaborate 3-device setup.